# C++ input validation - program is reading wrong values/not reading values

Tags: c++, validation, c++17

I am fairly new to C++ and need some help on a tic-tac-toe project that I am working on. Everything is completed except for the input, which I am having a lot of trouble with. Relevant pieces of my code and some input that breaks the program is below.

```cpp
cout << "Your move. Where would you like to play? Enter the row. Note that the row numbering starts at 0." << endl; // Ask for user input for move
if(started)
{
    cin.clear(); // Clear cin fail bit
    cin.sync(); // Sync cin buffer to get rid of lines left over
}
cin >> moveX; // Get row input from user

cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); // Ignore rest of line
cin.sync(); // Sync cin buffer to get rid of lines left over

if(validateMoveX(moveX) == -1) // If the move was not validated
{
    cout << "TOO MANY INVALID ATTEMPTS...EXITING" << endl << endl; // Tell the user that there were too many invalid attempts
    return ' '; // Return a space to main
}
cout << "Your move. Where would you like to play? Enter the column. Note that the column numbering starts at 0." << endl; // Ask for user input for move
cin.sync();  // Sync cin buffer to get rid of letters stuck in buffer
cin.clear(); // Clear cin fail bit
cin >> moveY; // Get the column input from user
cin.sync();  // Sync buffer to get rid of letters left over
cin.clear(); // Clear cin fail bit
cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); // Ignore rest of line
if(validateMoveY(moveX, moveY, miniBoard) == -1) // If the move was not validated
{ 
    cout << "TOO MANY INVALID ATTEMPTS...EXITING" << endl << endl; // Tell the user that there were too many invalid attempts
    return ' '; // Return space to main
}
```

Above is my code from the function that actually plays the game and calls all the other functions that are used in my program. I think this is where the issue lies, but I am not certain. The issue could also be in my Y-input validation function (probably the `cin.ignore()` line just before `cin >> moveY`). I think my X-input validation function is fine (again, not 100% sure)

Code from my function to validate user input for rows: https://pastebin.com/v3VtLbJ4

Code from my function to validate user input for columns: https://pastebin.com/cqfWTc05

Test data that breaks program:

Row input: 1 2

Column input: asdjfasjldksk sdlfasl ljk (basically random input)

Problem: Program reads this as "Play a move at 1, 0"

OR

Row input: put something random

Column input: 100000000000

After the program asks to re-enter input for the column: 1

Problem: The second "1" is not read

Comment: Your program is reading one integer and then very deliberately and explicitly skipping the rest of the line. You even have a comment there, "Ignore rest of line". Thus, if the input is `1 2` on one line, it will read `1` and ignore `2`.

Comment: Yes, I understand this - the program is only supposed to read 1 value in the "enter row input" section, and 1 value in the "enter column input" section. When I enter `1 2`, I want the program to **only read the 1.** In the first case that I presented, I believe the program is correctly reading the `1`, but for some reason, it is reading `asdjfasjldksk sdlfasl ljk` as `0`, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: What do you expect `cin >> moveY` to read when the input is `asdjfasjldksk` and `moveY` is, apparently, `int`? What value, if not `0`, do you expect `moveY` to have afterwards?

Comment: I was expecting `moveY` to store the ascii value of the first letter, `a`. If this is not the case in this sort of input, how should I get it to work (preferably while still keeping `moveY` as an `int`)? If it is not possible to keep `moveY` as an `int`, should I change `moveY` to a string and use the `stoi` function instead?

Comment: `char temp; cin >> temp; moveY = temp;` would read an ASCII code of `a` into `moveY`. Not sure what good that does you, but here you are.